# Two popup menus for geodistance?

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, dynamic, interactive, popup

```
entity = RandomEntity["Country"]
cities = CityData[{Large, CanonicalName@entity}]



  Manipulate[
 {PopupMenu[x, cities], PopupMenu[y, cities]},
 Button["Random", entity = RandomEntity["Country"]], 
 Dynamic[DynamicGeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[cities], 
    GeoPath[{x, y}, "Geodesic"]}]]]
```

I have these lines of code and I want to create a geographic map that creates a GeoPath from city x to city y based on what the user chooses from the popup menu. The output is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
entity = RandomEntity["Country"]
```

[image]

```
cities = CityData[{Large, CanonicalName @ entity}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[DynamicGeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[cities], GeoPath[{x, y}, "Geodesic"]}],
{{x, First @ cities}, Thread[cities -> CommonName /@ cities], ControlType -> PopupMenu},
{{y, Last @ cities}, Thread[cities -> CommonName /@ cities], ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]